# Adding a <div> for every object in array

Tags: javascript, html, sql, arrays

If I do `sql.prepare("SELECT * FROM DB where VALUE >= ?").get(value)` it will return an array of the rows that are larger or equal to value. How can I make it and add a new `<div>` container with parts of the array inside as text?

Comment: so it returns an array of objects?

Comment: What server-side code are you using? Please post all the relevant code that you are using in your question.

Comment: Yes, it does. I don't have any code yet because I have no clue how to do it.

Answer (score 2):

It would be something like this:

```js
const array = ['it', 'is', 'for', 'example'];
const newDiv = document.createElement('div');
newDiv.innerHTML = 'Text at newly created div'
newDiv.innerHTML += '<br>' + array.join('<br>');
document.body.prepend(newDiv);
```

```css
div {
    margin: 8px;
    padding: 4px;
    border: 1px dashed black;
}
```

```html
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
      <h1>Some h1 text</h1>
      Some text in the body.
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: this works but it seems that it replaces everything in the page.

Comment: @1AndOnlyPika really? I checked it now - added h1 and text into body. Nothing is replaced. You can also append the new div to anywhere instead of body tag.

Comment: I mean everything inside the div, it goes to the bottom automatically

Comment: @1AndOnlyPika but the new div had no inside it. I updated the snippet. Now it doesn't replace innerHTML, but add the array elements to it. And you can use `prepend` to make it go to the top.

Answer (score 1):

The question is still unclear but if it's an array of objects you want to return you could do something like this:

```js
const data = [
  { column1: 'bar1', column2: 'bar2', column3: 'bar3'},
  { column1: 'foo1', column2: 'foo2', column3: 'foo3'},
  { column1: 'rab1', column2: 'rab2', column3: 'rab3'}
];
const templateRow = (dataEntry) => `<div class="row">${dataEntry.column1} | ${dataEntry.column2} (${dataEntry.column3})</div>`;

const setup = () => {
  const body = document.querySelector('body');

  const div = document.createElement('div');
  div.classList.add('table');
  data.forEach(dataEntry => createRow(div, dataEntry));

  body.appendChild(div);
}

const createRow = (target, data) => {
  const html = templateRow(data);
  target.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', html);

}

window.addEventListener('load', setup);
```

```css
body {
  font-family: verdana;
}
```

Comment: but what if I wanted to put it like bar1 | foo1 (rab)

Comment: Are you referring that the values on separated from array entries? Otherwise, it's just an update to the template. I updated the post.

Comment: I have a feeling your data model is a bit special but If I understand it correctly. Are you looking for something like this??? https://jsfiddle.net/njb7m6dq/1/

Comment: Yes, thats exactly what I want it as but I will need to change it a bit. I'll try it out and see how it works. Is there a way to make it say a message like "nothing here" if there is nothing in the array?

Comment: guess you can give it a default value like this: https://jsfiddle.net/9xyftmz8/1/

Comment: Edit: Small refactoring: https://jsfiddle.net/z2mj6ehs/